# Error when returning to home with the scroll view

Tags: flutter, scroll, view

I have a scroll views that works correctly but when the operation is finished and it returns to home it throws an error and the scroll views is no longer executable.

Console error:

```
======== Exception caught by gesture ===============================================================
The following assertion was thrown while handling a gesture: ScrollController attached to multiple scroll views. 'package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_controller.dart': Failed assertion: line 108 pos 12: '_positions.length == 1'

Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause. In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=2_bug.md

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#2 ScrollController.position (package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_controller.dart:108:12) 
#3 PageController.animateToPage (package:flutter/src/widgets/page_view.dart:197:41) 
#4 ServicesProvider.selectCategory (package:agenda_booking/providers/servides_provider.dart:73:21) 
#5 _CategoriesCarousel.build.. (package:agenda_booking/pages/home_page.dart:212:45) 
#6 _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:1005:21) 
#7 GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:198:24) 
#8 TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:613:11) 
#9 BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:298:5) 
#10 BaseTapGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:269:7) 
#11 GestureArenaManager.sweep (package:flutter/src/gestures/arena.dart:157:27) 
#12 GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:449:20) 
#13 GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:425:22) 
#14 RendererBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:329:11) 
#15 GestureBinding._handlePointerEventImmediately (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:380:7) 
#16 GestureBinding.handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:344:5) 
#17 GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:302:7) 
#18 GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:285:7) 
#22 _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:170:10) 
#23 PlatformDispatcher._dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:331:7) 
#24 _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:94:31) (elided 5 frames from class _AssertionError and dart:async) Handler: "onTap" Recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer#340e5 debugOwner: GestureDetector state: ready won arena finalPosition: Offset(105.0, 340.0) finalLocalPosition: Offset(20.0, 42.0) button: 1 sent tap down.
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have attached the same ScrollController to multiple scroll position. If you could so me the code where you have implemented the scrollcontroller I could be of more help. Plus you can also checkout the official documentation here https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollController-class.html about scrollPosition and Scrollcontroller

Comment: Could you give me an idea of ​​what could be the solution?

Comment: Yeah please check your code and see if you have assigned the same scrollcontroller to multiple widgets. If you found one. Just replace the scrollcontroller with unique controllers for each widget and hopefully your problem will be resolved.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).